# Finding $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{x^2}\ln(1+t+t^2)dt}{\int_{0}^{x}\ln(1+t^3)dt}$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I have this limit:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{x^2}\ln(1+t+t^2)dt}{\int_{0}^{x}\ln(1+t^3)dt}$$

I'm thinking of L'Hospital after using antiderivates, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Use L'Hospital.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using L'Hospital you get:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x\ln(1+x^2+x^4)}{\ln(1+x^3)}$$

Now use the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln (1+x)}{ x} = 1$ :

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2x(x^2+x^4)}{(x^3)} = 2$$

Comment: Oh you are looking for [leibnitz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: @123 A stupid error! Thanks for pointing out!